# Decoding http2 frame header/data in Go

Tags: http, go, http2

I am trying to read from a tcp connection which contains HTTP/2 data. Below is the code for reading HEADERS frame -

```
framer := http2.NewFramer(conn, conn)
frame, _ := framer.ReadFrame()

fmt.Printf("fh type: %s\n", frame.Header().Type)
fmt.Printf("fh type: %d\n", frame.Header().Type)
fmt.Printf("fh flag: %d\n", frame.Header().Flags)
fmt.Printf("fh length: %d\n", frame.Header().Length)
fmt.Printf("fh streamid: %d\n", frame.Header().StreamID)
headersframe := (frame1.(*http2.HeadersFrame))
fmt.Printf("stream ended? %v\n", headersframe.StreamEnded())
fmt.Printf("block fragment: %x\n", headersframe.HeaderBlockFragment())
```

I send request using curl as -

```
curl -v https://127.0.0.1:8000/ -k --http2
```

This is the output I get (after reading connection preface and SETTINGS), if I read from the conn using above code -

```
fh type: HEADERS
fh type: 1
fh flag: 5
fh length: 30
fh streamid: 1
stream ended? true
block fragment: 828487418a089d5c0b8170dc6c4d8b7a8825b650c3abb6f2e053032a2f2a
```

I understand the ouput, except the **block fragment** part and how to decode it into ascii string? I want to know the protocol/method/url path information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using Go hpack library (https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack) -

```
decoder := hpack.NewDecoder(2048, nil)
hf, _ := decoder.DecodeFull(headersframe.HeaderBlockFragment())
for _, h := range hf {
      fmt.Printf("%s\n", h.Name + ":" + h.Value)
}
```

This prints -

```
:method:GET
:path:/
:scheme:https
:authority:127.0.0.1:5252
user-agent:curl/7.58.0
accept:*/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The "header block fragment" is encoded using [HPACK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541).

Go has an implementation to encode and decode HPACK, so you don't have to write your own.

You can find [here](https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/go-http2-hpack) an example of using both the encoder and decoder Go API.

Comment: So I tried using hpack package and doing hpack.HuffmanDecodeToString(headersframe.HeaderBlockFragment()), but this gives error {hpack: invalid Huffman-encoded data}